# Python: tool to keep track of deployments

Tags: python, deployment, web-deployment

I'm looking for a tool to keep track of "what's running where". We have a bunch of servers, and on each of those a bunch of projects. These projects may be running on a specific version (hg tag/commit nr) and have their requirements at specific versions as well.

Fabric looks like a great start to do the actual deployments by automating the ssh part. However, once a deployment is done there is no overview of what was done.

Before reinventing the wheel I'd like to check here on SO as well (I did my best w/ Google but could be looking for the wrong keywords). Is there any such tool already?

(In practice I'm deploying Django projects, but I'm not sure that's relevant for the question; anything that keeps track of pip/virtualenv installs or server state in general should be fine)

many thanks,

Klaas

==========

EDIT FOR TEMP. SOLUTION

==========

For now, we've chosen to simply store this information in a simple key-value store (in our case: the filesystem) that we take great care to back up (in our case: using a DCVS). We keep track of this store with the same deployment tool that we use to do the actual deploys (in our case: fabric)

Passwords are stored inside a TrueCrypt volume that's stored inside our key-value store.

==========

I will still gladly accept any answer when some kind of Open Source solution to this problem pops up somewhere. I might share (part of) our solution somewhere myself in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

`pip freeze` gives you a listing of all installed packages. Bonus: if you redirect the output to a file, you can use it as part of your deployment process to install all those packages (pip can programmatically install all packages from the file).

I see you're already using virtualenv. Good. You can run `pip freeze -E myvirtualenv > myproject.reqs` to generate a dependency file that doubles as a status report of the Python environment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm already using pip freeze, I was wondering if the is some kind of comprehensive tool to track the state of multiple projects (with possibly multiple versions) over multiple servers.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want something like [Opscode](http://www.opscode.com/) [Chef.](https://github.com/opscode/chef/)

In their own words:

> Chef works by allowing you to write
>   recipes that describe how you want a
>   part of your server (such as Apache,
>   MySQL, or Hadoop) to be configured.
>   These recipes describe a series of
>   resources that should be in a
>   particular state - for example,
>   packages that should be installed,
>   services that should be running, or
>   files that should be written. We then
>   make sure that each resource is
>   properly configured, only taking
>   corrective action when it's
>   neccessary. The result is a safe,
>   flexible mechanism for making sure
>   your servers are always running
>   exactly how you want them to be.

**EDIT:** Note Chef is not a Python tool, it is a general purpose tool, written in Ruby (it seems). But it is capable of supporting various "cookbooks", including one for installing/maintaining [Python apps.](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/python)

Comment: That's still not quite it: I'm more looking for a more elegant solution for keeping track of a bunch of projects on various servers than that I'm looking for the actual way of getting code on servers. The latter problem appears to be solved in various ways, the former is not.

Comment: Keeping track of what's installed where is pretty much "the secret sauce". People/entities who do it well, don't seem to be very outspoken about it. Probably because the said "sause" is very infrastructure-specific.